# .gitignore ignore folder with '@' symbol in path

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to add an exception to my `.gitignore` file to include my team's custom `npm` packages in our repository, so we can work with vendors without giving them the password to our private account.

I'm trying this:

```
node_modules/
!node_modules/@our-team
```

But `.gitignore` does not pick it up and start including that folder. Any ideas?

I'm on Windows but need to support Mac as well.

Comment: I know it looks at first like the other question is about something else—but this is the problem: once Git is able to exclude the entire directory `node_modules/`, Git never looks *inside* it to see `node_modules/@our-team` and hence never finds the override. If you ignore `node_modules/*` instead of `node_modules`, Git will have to look inside `node_modules` to find `*` to ignore.

Comment: Thank you, that's the actual source of the issue here!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\` to escape the `@` symbol

```
!node_modules/\@our-team
```

Find more info on [`gitignore`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore) files.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in quotes `!"node_modules/@our-team"`

Source: just tested with `git check-ignore`